# 'Automobile' vs 'car': How are these two words different?

Tags: word-choice

My layman's impression is that when people say 'automobile', they mean exactly the same thing as a 'car', except they're trying to be more formal.

Is that right? Or are there other differences?

Comment: A layman would be happy to call an 18-wheel tractor-trailer or a 40-seat bus an *automobile*, but wouldn't call them *cars*.

Comment: @DanBron - Most folks in the US would not call either of those an "automobile".

Comment: @DanBron Automobiles are usually 4-wheeled personal vehicles that carry a small number of passengers. Freight trucks and buses are often not considered automobiles, either colloquially or legally (in the US at least).

Comment: They do, however, qualify as automotive (or motor) vehicles. But automobiles? No.

Answer (score 9):

The terms are roughly synonymous, but do have distinct uses that set them apart from each other as well.  They both point to classes of vehicles, however the complete range of vehicles that would be encompassed be each term form distinct but overlapping sets.

Firstly **car** *can* refer to objects that aren't automobiles - railway carriages for example:

> Full Definition of CAR
>
> **1** :  a vehicle moving on wheels: as
>
> - *a* archaic :  carriage, chariot
> - *b* :  a vehicle designed to move on rails (as of a railroad)
> - *c* :  automobile
>
> **2** :  the passenger compartment of an elevator
>
> **3** :  the part of an airship or balloon that carries the passengers and cargo
>
> *source*: [Merriam-webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/car)

Secondly **automobile** can be used as a general classifying term that is inclusive of vehicles other than cars (and not inclusive of non-wheeled, non-self-propelling instances of "car", such as airship gondolas *etc*.) as per:

[image: Classes of Automobile]

*source*: http://what-when-how.com/automobile/general-classification-of-automobiles/

Comment: If you elaborate and substantiate your final para, you'll earn an upvote from me, at the very least.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of including the diagram you found directly into your answer, then upvoting you. If that's a bridge too far, I won't complain if you rollback.

Comment: Thanks for that - I was busy editing myself, so I didn't rollback, but did lose some of your effort sorry.

Comment: I love your additional edits. This is a very helpful, comprehensive, and well-sourced answer now. If I had another +1 to give, I would. Well done.

Comment: That's an unusual usage of 'automobile', certainly not the default in the UK and I'd say not in the US either.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In the U.S., automobile seems generally more generic than car. It depends on context, though. If I wanted to describe to you my vehicle, I would probably not use 'car' if my 'car' were a pick-up or S.U.V., for example. Somehow the word sounds too 'small' for such vehicles, at least to my ears. By contrast, the place you take your vehicle for repairs is normally called the "auto shop" or "auto repair shop". I think in the UK I think one would call that a garage, but that word is used for something else in the U.S.

Comment: @Brandin I'm talking about classing 'bus', 'scooter' etc under 'automobile'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What's odd about classifying 'bus' as an 'automobile'? It seems perfectly natural to me.

Comment: @Brandin Collins strongly differentiates between typical US and UK usage.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say there is no difference in meaning. The two term came into use meaning "a motor vehicle with four wheels; usually propelled by an internal combustion engine; " about the same year (1895/1896). I agree with you that automobile may sound less colloquial,  car is the more used expression.

[Automobile](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=automobile&allowed_in_frame=0):

> - ***"self-propelled motor vehicle," 1895, from French automobile, short for véhicule automobile***.In English other early forms were motorcar and autocar.

[Car](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=car&allowed_in_frame=0):

> - c. 1300, "wheeled vehicle," from Anglo-French carre.
>   ***Extension to "automobile" is by 1896,*** but from 1831 to the first decade of 20c. the cars meant "railroad train."

(Etymonline)

Comment: Is a public bus (say, the [M86](http://web.mta.info/mta/planning/sbs/86St_M86.html)) an automobile? Is it a car?

Comment: I'd say It is a public vehicle. Are you referring to the expression 'streetcar'?

Comment: No, a streetcar is a trolley; a different use of *car* (what the Brits call a *carriage*, one independent part of a train). I was asking because people I know (i.e. laymen) would be happy to call a bus an *automobile*, but **not** a *car*, so they're different. Yes, a bus is also a public vehicle, but then so is the Staten Island ferry, and it is neither an automobile nor a car. By a similar thought process, my friends who bought a fancy and expensive SUV would be unhappy if you called it a *car*: they'd insist on *truck* or *SUV*; but nevertheless it is an automobile. Similarly for a pickup.

Comment: Those are interesting nuances which are probably confined, for the moment, to those whose car is their 'religion'. I know a few of them. Generally speaking, by layman I mean someone who is  not that much into motors, I think the two terms mostly coincide.

Answer (score 1):

Merriam Webster make you suppose that automobile is the normal word for car. This is a weak point of dictionaries that they don't hint at the main variant. Google Ngram shows that the normal variant is car. And automobile is a relatively seldom used variant in written language. It is much too long for spoken language.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=automobile%2C%20car&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cautomobile%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccar%3B%2Cc0)

Have a look at synonyms for car at Merriam Webster or The Free Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Examples of cars that are not automobiles:

> **car** NOUN
> ...
> 1.1 A railroad vehicle for passengers or freight.
> ‘the first-class cars’
> 1.2 The passenger compartment of an elevator, cableway, airship, or balloon.
> ‘he was in the elevator when the car stuck’
> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/car)

Comment: The two definitions you list are correct but they're specific to a very special context. I think the OP context is asking about roadway vehicles.

Answer (score -6):

The term "automobile" has begun in France in the late 19th century describing the new mode of transportation, and the word quickly spread to other European countries and to the United States of America. Then, the word "car" was a broader term that referring to a wheeled vehicle like a carriage or a cart.

In Great Britain, "car" has later been specialized for self-propelled vehicles mainly with the impact of British car manufacturers like Rolls-Royce and Bentley, helping to popularize the term in the early 20th century.

While either word is interchangeable in both dialects, the word "car" is preferred in British English, while "automobile" is preferred in American English. The word "automobile" may also be more formal or technical than "car".

Comment: Some evidence would be good, whether it's statistical, a usage guide, or some other source.

Comment: How can the United States favor "automobile" when "car" appears about 30 times more often then "automobile" in American English (according to [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/))?

Comment: @StuartF I have edited the answer to include references.

Comment: In your dictionary reference for "car", the first definition is "automobile" and the second relates to vehicles on rails...So this doesn't seem to support your contention that "car" is mainly used for vehicles on rails.

Comment: I should point out that Americans relatively rarely encounter rail cars in daily life, so we rarely talk about them at all, except in historical contexts.